# How to create a listview for each list item of a listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Basically, what I have is a listView and each list item itself contains a list of item to be shown.

I tried putting the sublist inside the adapter layout of parent list but that only displays the item at 0th position in child or sublist.

Let me know how to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: There is an expandable listview object

Answer (score 0):

try the `ExpandableListView` its designed for this kind of issues

Comment: Sublist can have any random number of list item. So that wouldn't solve my problem. For example - I have two list items and 10-10 sublist items inside each of these parent list items

Comment: you mean listview > listview > lisview

Comment: No it is just list -> list

Comment: I think since its just a one level nested List then the Expandable will do it .. give it a try any way .